# Counter is not displaying output

Tags: javascript

I now realize that I commented and it did not go out to everyone, so I will update here. I have changed the variables and if statements. That portion works. I have also edited the code to reflect both variables, count and i. Count is a typical timer variable, which increments every second. Variable i is the same except I divided it by 5000 to make it increment every 5 seconds.

As it stands now, i is still incrementing beyond 500 though. I have now declared i outside of the entire function and now it stops incrementing i. However, when I refresh, it will give me an incremented number.

1. When i hits 500, it needs to save whatever value it has so it can be added to the next day's total when the timer (count) starts over at 0 at midnight and begins again. Since I need i to keep its value, I did not pass i to clearInterval() like I did with count.

Here is the updated if statement to reflect what I'm trying to do.

```
    if (count >= 0 && i < 500) {

        count = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - d.getTime()) / 1000);
        i = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 5000 );
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = i;
     if (i >= 500)   {
        clearInterval(i);
        }      
      }

}
```

The second thing I'm trying to accomplish is at midnight once again (and every night thereafter) the count will reset to 0 and begin counting seconds again. I will have retained the value from yesterday (first day 500, second day add 500 to whatever the total will be...so if it is 500-the daily max- it would be a total of 1000 on the second day, etc). The results of i will be displayed on the browser.

Hope I made myself more clear in what I'm trying to do. Thank you in advance!

---

I am trying to make a counter that will begin incrementing i by 1 every minute beginning on 1/1/2017. It should increment automatically without refreshing the browser and display in the div. 
My current code is not outputting anything. But I also doubt that it is set up properly to increment every second. Can anyone please help? Thank you.
`<div id="count"></div><br/>`
 is blank though with no numbers. What am I doing wrong in this stage? Thanks.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('count');
     function updateCount() {
         var d = new Date();
         // set d to midnight
         d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
         d.setMonth(0);
         d.setDate(1);
         d.setFullYear(2017);
  if (count < 0) {
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "Check back January 1, 2017.";
    }
      if (count => 0) && (i < 500)  {
         var count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 1000 );
        var i = 0;     
         i++;
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = i;
        }
}
    
 updateCount();
 setInterval(updateCount, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="count"></div><br/>
```

Comment: I think here is the error `if (count => 0) && (i < 500)  {`, its: `>=`

Comment: And `count` variable is not declared in your JavaScript

Comment: I added the >= but still no output.

Comment: You have not declared your count variable and you write wrong if condition.use this if (count >= 0 && i < 500)  {

Comment: @Klinger The `count` variable is not declared before accessed the first time by `if (count < 0)`

Comment: Declare variable `i` and `count` globally, Above the function. @user7347402

Comment: I originally had count declared outside the if block. But since I was trying to make the i increment every second I thought js would connect them if it was declared in there similar to a do while approach. Hasty judgement call in my troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code. Change the date.

```
<body><div id="count"></div><br/>

 <script type='text/javascript'>

var div = document.getElementById('count');

function updateCount() {
var count=0;
    var d = new Date();
    var i = 0; 

    // set d to midnight

    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    d.setMonth(12);

    d.setDate(28);

    d.setFullYear(2016);





        count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 1000 );




        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count;



    if (count < 0) {



         document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "Check back January 1, 2017.";

}

}



updateCount();

setInterval(updateCount, 1000);



</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if (count => 0) && (i < 500)` must be like this `if (count >= 0 && i < 500)`

And variables `count` and `i` must be declared before to use them.

I didn't understand your logic correctly. But made necessary code corrections to display output, may not be the desired output.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('count');
var count = 0;
var i = 0;


function updateCount() {

    var d = new Date();

    // set d to midnight

    d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    d.setMonth(0);

    d.setDate(1);

    d.setFullYear(2017);





    if (count <= 0) {



      document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "Check back January 1, 2017.";

    }



    if (count >= 0 && i < 500) {

      count = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - d.getTime()) / 1000);
      i++;
      document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = i;
      }
  }


    updateCount();

    setInterval(updateCount, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="count"></div>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole code:
*with stop timer*

```js
var div = document.getElementById('count');
var d = new Date(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0); //new Date(2016, 11, 29, 0, 0, 0);
var count = 1;
var i = 0;

function updateCount() {
  count = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - d.getTime()) / 1000);

  console.log(count);

  if (count < 0) {
    div.innerHTML = "Check back on January 1, 2017.";
  } else if (i < 500) {
    i++;
    div.innerHTML = i;
  } else {
    // Stop the timer
    clearTimeout(counter);
  }
}

var counter = setInterval(updateCount, 1000);
```

```html
Counter
<div id="count"></div>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this

```js
var div = document.getElementById('count');
var count = 0,i = 0;
var d = new Date();
// set d to midnight
d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
d.setMonth(0);
d.setDate(1);
d.setFullYear(2017);

function updateCount() {
    if (count <= 0) {
      div.innerHTML = "Check back January 1, 2017.";
    }

    if (count >= 0 && i < 500) {
          count = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - d.getTime()) / 1000);
          i++;
          div.innerHTML = i;
      }
  }

updateCount();
setInterval(updateCount, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="count"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d = new Date();

function updateCount(start) {
  
  if(start) {
    d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    d.setMonth(0);
    d.setDate(1);
    d.setFullYear(2017);
  } else {
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1000 * 60);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = [d.getMonth()+1,
               d.getDate(),
               d.getFullYear()].join('/')+' '+
              [d.getHours(),
               d.getMinutes()].join(':');
}

updateCount(true);

setInterval(updateCount, 60 * 1000);
```

```html
<div id="count"></div>
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I was able to fix the if loop and the variiables are declared outside now. I have i printing, but as everyone (including myself) has noticed, due to the i++ in the second if statement, it will only increment 1.

Comment: This leads me into my mode of confusion now when I look at my code. How do I match the math function with the increments to make i increment every second but not go above 500? (I think I got the 500 right with the if beginning but unsure how to get i to increment with seconds). And what if I wanted to do something more advanced like incrementing every 5 seconds without a refresh? (5000 milliseconds in the parameters as opposed to 1000).

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you need? I will try to modify my snippet.

Comment: I updated the main question with an explanation and an updated if statement.

Answer (score -1):

There are many errors in the code it needs to be `if ((count => 0) && (i < 500)) {` and there are redeclaration of variable `count`. Also the value of `i` will always be 1 as it resets at 0 within the if condition. You need to fix the logical condition to make it work.